# Properly handling errors in init

Tags: objective-c

How should I properly handle errors in an initialiser which performs various configurations of the object during creation?

Would it be a *bad* to throw an exception? What about returning NSError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well seeing how your `init`  method returns type `id` or more recently, `instancetype`, you cannot return an `NSError *`. Exceptions seem like the way to go for your situation. With these, you have two choices.

**Choice 1** Throwing Exceptions. In this case, if you see something going wrong, just throw an exception.

```
- (id)init {
    ...
    ...
    if (shouldThrowException) 
        NSException *myException = [NSException new]
        ... populate this exception with details ...
        @throw(myException)
}
```

**Choice 2** Catching Exceptions. In this case, if you do not care what goes wrong, you can just ignore any exceptions raised.

```
- (id)init {
    ...
    ...
    @try {
        // some dangerous thing
    } @catch (NSException *e) {}
}
```